# Limit amount of entries a user can create based on their user group

Tags: entries, user-groups

Is there a way to enforce a limit to the amount of entries a user can create based on their user group

I’ve been digging around a little and can’t seem to find anything that would allow this, I’ve looked at adding my own permissions but I don’t think that’s right as I need/want the value to be a number, not a ‘can the user add x amount’ kinda deal.

Something like:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section(‘listing’).authorId(user.id) %}

{% if entries.count >= userGroup.entryLimit %}
    No more entries for you!
{% else %}
    More entries for you!
{% endif %}
```

Is the only way to do this by creating a custom plugin?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a custom plugin is going to be the way to go with this.  Your template code would look something like:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section(‘listing’).authorId(user.id) %}

{% if entries.count >= craft.myPlugin.getEntryLimitForUser(user.id) %}
    No more entries for you!
{% else %}
    More entries for you!
{% endif %}
```

Your plugin would also hook onto the [onSaveEntry](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#entries-onSaveEntry) event and keep an incrementing entry save counter for each user you're tracking.

Comment: If anyones interested in achieving this, I have created a little plugin that seems to do the trick, its on Github.

https://github.com/alecritson/Curbed-Craft